# How to send JSON object/string (as 'POST') to a webservice using $resource in angularjs

Tags: json, web-services, angularjs

I'm an absolute newbie in angularjs and don't have any idea about web services either.
My requirement is something like this:

I'll have a basic login page (to be designed using html and angularjs) which is going to ask for my credentials (Username and Password). On providing a set of credentials and clicking on the "Submit" button, my code needs to process the form data and pass the information on to a webservice. I just have the url of the webservice with me and nothing else.
Thus my principal objective would be to send across the username and password to the webservice (preferably as a JSON object) and check whether its working properly or not. So far, I've successfully managed to:

1> Hit the webservice (I've used $resource for doing the same.)
2> Store the username and password as a JSON object.

Now I need to accomplish two things:

1> send this data as "POST" and most importantly, 2> send this JSON data(as an object or string) to the webservice.

I'm absolutely clueless...Please help me out by modifying my code.

Thanks in advance. Here's my JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$resource) {
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

$scope.checkUsername = function(){

var USERNAME = $scope.inputUsername;
var PASSWORD = $scope.inputPassword;

var f = JSON.stringify({USERNAME: USERNAME, PASSWORD: PASSWORD });

var result= JSON.parse(f);

var Something = $resource("/some url/:id", {id: "@id"},
      {
      post:{
          method:"POST",
          isArray:false
           },
      });
  $scope.something = Something.get({id:1});

  $scope.alertMessage = "Web service has been successfully hit!";


};

});
```

And here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Authentication</title>

<script src="C:\Users\Rup\Desktop\POC2\js\angular.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Rup\Desktop\POC2\js\angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Rup\Desktop\POC2\experiment_2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <form name="form1" class="form-horizontal">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Username</label> <input
                 type="text" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username"
                 ng-model="inputUsername"> <br /> <label
                 class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label> <input
                 type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"
                 ng-model="inputPassword"> <br /> <span class="help-block">{{alertMessage}}</span>
          <br />
          <!--<a class="btn">Sign in</a>-->
          <button ng-click="checkUsername()">Submit</button>
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that this should be fairly straight forward.  You have the right idea, you just need to extend the resource object as you have done with "post" method, and when you call it - pass in your JSON object.  Angular will then append the passed in JSON object as post parameters automatically.  It's a good idea (I've read), to create this User resource as a service/factory so that you can inject it into your controllers to abstract the calls to the server.  As an example - something I have done would be to create the service like so (with a dependency on the angular $resource):

```
var myApp = angualar.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('UserService', ["$resource", 
        function UserService($resource) {
            var UserService = $resource('/rest/user', {}, {
                search: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: window.location.origin +'/yourServer/rest/search' //custom url of your service to be called 
                }
            });

            return UserService;
        }
    ])
```

Then in your controller, you inject the service to be used, and create a method that then calls your shiny new service:

```
myApp.controller("myAppController", ["$scope", "UserService", 
        function myAppCtrl($scope, UserService) {

    $scope.search = function () {
        var params = {
         param1: "searchValue1",
         param2: "searchValue2"
        }
        var response = UserService.search(params);
        response.$promise.then(
            function success() {
                //celebrate!

            }, 
            function fail(err) {
                //comiserate
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The response object from the call to the service method is a promise, which you attach your success or fail functions to be called when the call successfully returns or fails.